# Synchronous query?

Tags: android, parse-platform, synchronous

How to implement synchronous query with parse in android?
I want something like below, but the synchronous way.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyClass");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
         if (e == null) {
             objectsWereRetrievedSuccessfully(objects);
         } else {
             objectRetrievalFailed();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: new AsyncTask to perform a time-consuming operation

Comment: I don't want to do this with async, I want to get 2 strings with sync way,if I don't do this with this way, slideshow will be crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ParseQuery#find()`](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#find()) to perform the query and block until it is finished. Something like the following should work:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyClass");
try {
    List<ParseObject> objects = query.find();
    objectsWereRetrievedSuccessfully(objects);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    objectRetrievalFailed();
}
```

However, as already mentioned by others, blocking the main thread is generally not a good idea as doing so makes the UI unresponsive.

Comment: Thanks,it works! Yes, I know, it's not the best way to get data, but it's only 2 strings , so it's very fast.